# How to make hyperref link boxes in XeLaTeX as big as they are in pdfLaTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref

When typesetting the following sample using `xelatex`, the various clickable link-boxes produced using `\ref`, `\cite`, `\footnote`, `\href`, etc. are small and ugly, and sometimes make it hard to read the enclosed number or text.  How can we make the link-boxes bigger, as they appear when running the same code through `pdflatex`?

```
% hyperref-xelatex.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\label{one}

Link to section \ref{one}

This text has a footnote.\footnote{Some explanation here}

We are quoting from a book \cite{book}.

Now we want to \href{www.example.com}{link somewhere} or like this \url{www.example.com}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{book}
This book needs no title

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you compared the output in different PDF viewers?

Answer (score 3):

the `xdvipdfmx` driver has a `-g` option to control the padding added to these links and other annotations, you can pass that option through from xetex by using

```
xelatex --output-driver='xdvipdfmx -g 1pt '
```

to add an extra 1pt of space.

The image shows an unchanged copy of your test file set with pdflatex, xelatex, or xelatex using the above option.

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for the font choice :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik a little present for egreg when he comes past.

Comment: Imho `\hypersetup{pdflinkmargin=4pt}` should work too (in a current tex system).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ooh obviously the current maintainers of hyperref would know such a thing... (or at least one of them:-)

Comment: Nonzero  -g  option breaks the nice animation controls of the animate package. Not only modifies it the size of links, but also of any PDF annotation in the document.

Comment: @AlexG I don't suppose we can simply blame the author of the animate package for that unfortunate fact??? (I did add an "and other annotations" rider as a hint that this may change more than just links...)

Comment: Better use colorlinks vor ocgcolorlinks.

Comment: @AlexG you know much more about this than me, could you post an answer?

Comment: Yes, button Widgets are affected, for example.