# xelatex hyperref bounding box

Tags: xetex, hyperref

I've got this code here

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

% ----- Packages -----
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}       % make e.g. toc clickable

% ----- Settings -----
\KOMAoptions{
        paper=a4,           % set papersize
        fontsize=12pt,      % set fontsize to 12pt
        parskip=half,       % half a line will seperate paragraphs
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\subsection{align left}
\subsection{align right}
\subsection{center}

\section{Section}
\subsection{sub1}
\subsection{sub2}

\end{document}
```

With produces with `pdflatex` this output:
[image: pdflatex] which I think looks fine.

But when I now compile it with `xelatex` I get this:
[image: xelatex]

With which I'm fine too, except that in my opinion the boxes produced by `hyperref` are way too large.

I already read something about boxes and `XeTeX` (page 25 in the manual), but somehow this is not helping. Does someone know a way arround this or how to reduce the size of the boxes (I only found the parameter to reduce the thickness of the box)?

EDIT: @Ruixi Zhang came up with the workaround of setting the `pdflinkmargin` (in hypersetup) to a negative value. This works when using only a small negative value (absolute small) then it looks ok (the left/right margin is reduced too by this parameter, so the boxes around links to footnotes are a bit slim), but not nice. So I'd still appreciate suggestions how to make this nice ;)

Comment: The hyperlink box is generated by “measuring” its content. For `pdfTeX`, the height and depth information comes from the traditional TFM (TeX font metric) files. You can see `1.3 center` has zero depth, while `1.2 align right` descends below the baseline. But for `XeTeX`, OpenType font is used (so there will be different metric information available). In your output the “bounding boxes” are the same size in height and depth. Presumably, the height is `Ascender` and the depth is `Descender` in the `OS/2` table.

Comment: Hm, that makes sense, but is there a way to manually intervene? Because in my opinion this doesn't look that nice...

Comment: Maybe this will do the trick: `\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{0pt}` or even `\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{-1pt}`. Check the `hyperref` manual for the `\XeTeXLinkBox` section.

Comment: No even with `-.5cm` or `-5pt` the boxes are still "too large".

Comment: Hmmm… Try `\hypersetup{pdflinkmargin=-1pt}`? This solution comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488496 (it appears that the size of link box is very driver dependent) But this may produce a link box too small on the left and right…

Comment: Yes exactly as you thought, when reducing too much, the box gets too small on the left. But I think for now this will be enough to make this look more nice. Nevertheless I'm still interested if there is a possibility to make this even better (only adjust the vertical margin or somehow use a `pdflatex` like engine for this)

Comment: Ask on the dvipdfmx mailing list https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/dvipdfmx. Perhaps the developer can give some insight how the box is calculated and which options exist to reduce the height.

Comment: Haven't looked closely to see if it will be helpful, but see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451037 and the other answers for some theoretical discussion.

Comment: Oh thanks @ShreevatsaR the discussion is interesting. And thanks to @UlrikeFischer, the suggestion with the mailing list works, there is now a new option `\AtBeginDvi{\special{dvipdfmx:config g 2pt,-2pt}}` that can be used to specify these margins separately